# past simple or past continious

Tags: past-tense

I’m just wondering what is the difference between the following sentences?

> How was your weekend going?

and

> How did your weekend go?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the weekend's events.

> How **was** your weekend going?

would be used if you were aware something changed during the weekend.

> My weekend was going well, until my girlfriend called me a liar and walked out.

while

> How **did** your weekend go?

is asking for general information about past events.

> We went to the beach and had so much fun.

Comment: It might be worth to note that not only must you be aware of something changing you must be talking about it. Even if you know his girlfriend walked out on him, you can't segue from a different topic using this as an opening.